# "List of tuples", from python to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, list

I am working with python and flask.
I have already my list of tuples in **python**:

```
[[[40.728410000000004, -73.99428], [40.728253333333335, -73.99441333333334], [40.72809666666667, -73.99454666666666], [40.727940000000004, -73.99468]], [[40.727940000000004, -73.99468], [40.72790666666667, -73.99470666666667], [40.727873333333335, -73.99473333333333], [40.72784, -73.99476]]]
```

Is necesary for pass this to javascript (*to my html file*) in JSON format, thus, in my javascript code I have a string, not a list of tuples.
code in python:

```
encoded = json.dumps(ListOfTuples)
output = {'vector': encoded}
return jsonify(**output)
```

Result in javascript, a string.

```
"[[[40.728410000000004, -73.99428], [40.728253333333335, -73.99441333333334], [40.72809666666667, -73.99454666666666], [40.727940000000004, -73.99468]], [[40.727940000000004, -73.99468], [40.72790666666667, -73.99470666666667], [40.727873333333335, -73.99473333333333], [40.72784, -73.99476]]]"
```

I need read this like a list of tuples in javascript. I am trying convert to a object, but is not working, whit this code:

```
var arr = Object.values(ListOfTuplesInString);
```

I have this:

```
["[", "[", "[", "4", "0", ".", "7", "2", "8", "4", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "4", ",", " ", "-", "7", "3", ".", "9", "9", "4", "2", "8", "]", ",", " ", "[", "4", "0", ".", "7", "2", "8", "2", "5", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "5", ",", " ", "-", "7", "3", ".", "9", "9", "4", "4", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "]", ",", " ", "[", "4", "0", ".", "7", "2", "8", "0", "9", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "7", ",", " ", "-", "7", "3", …]
```

How can I get my list of tuples in javascript?
Thanks.

Comment: Try JSON.parse(ListOfTuplesInString) instead. Note that tuples don't exist in JavaScript. it's all lists, but JS refers to them as arrays.

Comment: Thanks @LukeK, is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you convert to JSON twice? Once with json.dumps and once with jsonify?

You should just do:

```
return json.dumps({'vector': ListOfTuples})
```

Then chances will be good that your Ajax call (when issued with the correct content-type) will return a valid JS object. But the latter is just a guess since you did not provide how you get the data into JS.

Comment: thank you Falk, I just copy an answer from a tutorial. But I try this way, but I have an error when I try to use: 'JSON.parse(...)'